# how to remove values from a knockout list

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm failing to remove a string from a list using javascript together with knockout. Any advice appreciated, many thanks, James

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/4/

**Code snippet**

```
viewModel.toRemove = ko.observable();
viewModel.remove = function() {
    viewModel.Article.Keywords().remove(viewModel.toRemove());
}
```

In Chrome's console I get the error: "has no method 'remove'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `viewModel.Article.Keywords()` is a plain string, not an array.  Therefore, there is no `remove` function.

If the data does indeed return the list deilmited by pipes, then you can try to call the `replace` function on the string to remove the value (this doesn't account for removing the first value, and will also remove multiple entries if they have the same value):

```
var newKeywords = viewModel.Article.Keywords().replace("|" + viewModel.toRemove(), "");
viewModel.Article.Keywords(newKeywords);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/6/

**However, I don't recommend this solution.**  It is **much** better and less error-prone to use an actual array if possible.

In that case, you can simply call `Keywords.remove()` to remove an entry from the array.

See this fiddle (split original string into an array):  http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/8/

**or**

See this fiddle (data in JSON is already an array):  http://jsfiddle.net/rxkU3/7/

Comment: how easy is it to have the delete next to each adjacent value?

Comment: deletion of values :: http://jsfiddle.net/beauxjames/NqKUk/ || mark as answered per Joseph